# button clicks and running total in textbox

Tags: c#

everyone. I'm a relative newguy, so be gentle! I'm using C# 2019 and have a form to do for my work. Let's say
I have 4 buttons on my form, each with an assigned value that is displayed in a text box at the click. Button 1 has a value
of 5; button 2 has a value of 10; button 3 has a value of 15; button 4 has a value of 20. If I click the 1 button, I can
get the number 5 to appear in the text box. What I need now is for button 2 to be added to button 1, and display 15
in the text box. So if I click the 1 button again, I need to see a 20 in the text box. Basically, I just need the
successive button clicks to add their assigned values to the total in the text box. Please forgive me if that is.
posted in the wrong place. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean you want add every time and display added result in textbox ? Is it windows form or webforms ?

Comment: Can you please post the code for your button1 click handler?

Comment: @AmanB I think he doesn't have any code yet

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  but anyway you'll want to search for something along the lines of converting string to int then adding is just "x = x + y" or "x +=y"

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but I assume that you want to **add the button's value everytime you click them**. You can do this:

> You need a `List<int>` for the storage of those numbers everytime you
> click a button

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
```

> And then create a method that calculates all the values inside the
> List and return them.

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
public int Sum()
{
    int sum = 0;
    foreach(int number in numbers)
    {
        sum = sum + number;
    }
    
    return sum;
}
```

Then on your `Click Event`, add a number on the list then call the method

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int sum = Sum();
    numbers.Add(5);
    txtResult.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```